Object-oriented programming design with relational database tables
I want to understand what is considered best-practice to better align with OOP when handling relational databases. I cannot find any online examples where classes and a more maintainable/re-usable design is implemented for relational databases.
Say we have a few different relational database (CSV table) files:

Environment: primary_id (PK), event_id (FK), datetime (SK), weather, temperature, temperature_unit
Incident: primary_id (PK), event_id (FK), datetime (SK), incident_category, severity, reported_via
Reporter: primary_id (PK), event_id (FK), name, sex, occupation

where PK: primary keys, FK: foreign keys, SK: secondary keys.
A snapshot of the CSV table files where I display a few records per table as an example:
Environment:

1001678125, 10016781, 202401251123, sunny, 19, celsius
1024692335, 10246923, 202406120958, cloudy, 15, celsius

Incident:

1001678125, 10016781, 202401251123, main_entrance_breach, B, serious, police
1024692335, 10246923, 202406120958, side_entrance_breach, C, mild, reception

Reporter:

1001678125, 10016781, 202401251123, Joe, M, police officer
1024692335, 10246923, 202406120958, Dave, M, reception staff

The goal
The application would read each table, load it in an appropriate dataframe (e.g. pandas in Python) and have a variety of methods to exercise on a selection of the data records and carry out calculations on it. For example, one calculation method could be to calculate the number of serious incidents that occurred after 11pm where police was involved.
My idea of having each element (column header) as its own class was to enable the application to present more detailed information and carry out extra calculcations appropriate for each element. For example, the temperature (in combination with the temperature_unit) could have class methods to calculate the average temperature, have methods to categorise values (below 0 with a celsius unit to be labelled as "freezing"), etc.
But also, using OOP should enable the application to extend its functionality (more specific methods/calculations) or adapt to cases where the database file might have an extra column added to it.
This is why I would like to use proper Object-Oriented-Programming design and define classes for my key objects.
--
The OOP design I though of is the following:
An Element parent (base) class to capture the high-level details of what information each element (column header) would hold: name, abbreviated_name, value, description, data_file_used_in, column_pos_in_data_file, notes.
Create more low-level specific child (derived) classes, one for each specific element (column header), that inherit from the Element class. For example, a primary_id class, an event_id class, a datetime class, etc. each providing specific values to the Element class fields.
Where appropriate, create classes for specific data types. For example, the incident_category element can be one of the following values, A, B, or C.
Then, create a DatabaseFile parent (base) class to capture the details of each database file: filename, size, element(s) where element(s) is all of the element column headers found in a database file.
Finally, create child (derived) classes for each of the three specific database files: Environment, Incident, and Reporter. Each will hold specific values for that file as well as list all element (column headers) found in it.
Initially the data from each CSV file will be loaded into an appropriate data type, for example using the pandas package in Python: df = pandas.read_csv('environment.csv') and and an instance of the Environment class will be initialised. The intention is that each child class will hold specific methods to manipulate data.
--
Using Python pseudocode the above would look something like:
class Element:
    def __init__(self, name, abbreviated_name, value, description, data_file_used_in, column_pos_in_data_file, notes):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.abbreviated_name = abbreviated_name
        self.value = value
        self.description = description
        self.data_file_used_in = data_file_used_in
        self.column_pos_in_data_file = column_pos_in_data_file
        self.notes = notes


class Temperature(Element):
    def __init__(self, name, abbreviated_name, value, description, data_file_used_in, column_pos_in_data_file):
        Element.__init__(self, name, abbreviated_name, value, description, data_file_used_in, column_pos_in_data_file, notes)


class IncidentCategoryCode:
    VALID_CODES = {"A", "B", "C"}
    def __init_(self, code):
        if code not in self.VALID_CODES:
            raise ValueError()
        self.code = code


class IncidentCategory(Element):
    def __init__(self, name, abbreviated_name, value, description, data_file_used_in, column_pos_in_data_file, category_code):
        self.category_code = IncidentCategoryCode(category_code)
        Element.__init__(self, name, abbreviated_name, value, description, data_file_used_in, column_pos_in_data_file, notes)

 (...)

class DatabaseFile:
    def __init__(self, filename, size):
        self.filename = filename
        self.size = size


class Environment(DatabaseFile):
    def __init__(self, filename, date, size, *elementArgs):
        self.primary_id = elementArgs[0]
        self.event_id = elementArgs[1]
        self.datetime = elementArgs[2]
        self.weather = elementArgs[3]
        self.temperature = elementArgs[4]
        self.temperature_unit = elementArgs[5]
        DatabaseFile.__init__(self, filename, date, size)

(...)

--
Summary
In short, below is a mapping of the classes to the databases/elements reference in the Python pseudocode example:

Element is a parent class not mapped to a database file.
Temperature is child class of the Element class that maps to the element column header of the Environment database.
IncidentCategoryCode is data type for the IncidentCategory` class
IncidentCategory is a child class of the Element class that maps to the element column header of the incident database.
DatabaseFile is a parent class not mapped to a database file.
Environment is a child class of the DatabaseFile class that maps to the environment database.

--
Questions
Is the above design/implementation sensible - is there a better way (best practice) to design this? Also, should the primary/secondary/foreign key details be captured in the design?
For example,  is better to read all the tables and concatenate all the data (using the primary key) into a single dataframe, or should one maintain the separation and create three dataframes each with their corresponding data found in each CSV table file?

I removed the last sentence requesting offsite references or sources. That is off-topic for this community, and attracts unnecessary down-votes and close-votes.

What do you mean by a "secondary key"?

Can you [edit] your question to include how your classes map to database tables? You talk about an Element but it isn't clear what the table and columns are.

AFAIK, a candidate key not selected as a primary key is called secondary key.

I'm still not clear how the python code relates to the CSV files.

Can you [edit] your question to include some pseudo code for how your proposed classes will be used? The code in a class exists to serve the code using the class. I'm utterly confused about what you are trying to accomplish, because from an OOP perspective the code using your classes is what counts.

Added a mapping of the classes to the databases/elements for more clarity.

The question mentions "element" column headers, but I see no indication of what the column headers actually are or what kinds of values they contain.

And besides "mapping to a database", what should these classes do --- what is the behavior these classes encapsulate?

Edited the question to explain the CSV database tables with examples, a more explicit goal and questions. This should address most (if not all) of the issues raised by people at the comment section - hope this should be enough to make the question clear and within scope.  @GregBurghardt

@Yannis: your edit improved the question heavily, (though I am under impression it invalidated the existing answer). Still I think it is very broad, probably too broad for the Q&A format of this site. Asking just for a "better way" or "best practice" without any criteria what "best" means for your, or why you are not satisfied with your current solution is not really a solvable problem for our community. It may need a discussion, but the SE sites are not discussion sites, they are Q&A sites. See also https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8965

BTW, I voted to reopen your question. Thank you for spending the time to clarify this.

(Note:  The question had been substantially re-written after this answer was posted.   The original question seemed to be more about using OO to design a relational database, so this answer is focused on Entity-Relationship modelling, contrasted against OO Design).
Entities in a relational database are not "OO" objects
Don't fall into the trap of trying to mix OO design with Relational Database design;  OO and Relational Databases have fundamentally different goals, and are intended for completely different contexts to each other.

Relational Database design is based on Entity-Relationship Modelling, for data stored outside of your program in a relational structure.
OO Design evolved from procedural programming for modelling a program's behaviour and internal state.
One goal for Entity-Relationship modelling (relational database design) is to establish a set of rules which ensure data integrity whenever any data is Inserted/Updated/Deleted.
Another goal for Entity-Relationship modelling is to minimise the impact of future changes to the schema when requirements change.   Once real data is in the database, the cost, risk and complexity of migrating to a new structure tends to increase a lot - particularly changes which might change the semantics or integrity of existing data.
One goal for OO design is to use abstraction to express a program's behaviour and state at a higher level than traditional procedural code.
Another goal for OO design is to have a program structure which is really easy to change as your users' requirements evolve.

OO, Behaviour and Code Flexibility
When designing behaviour, people typically focus on users' needs/requirements;  such as the functionality they expect and the problems they want to solve; for example, by thinking about their UX, interactivity, 'journeys' through the system, outcomes from those journeys.
Ideally the code would be expressed in a way which allows someone who understands user requirements to be able to follow and understand how the code relates back to something that users/stakeholders understand from the 'real-world' business/problem domain.
Code is something which developers are likely going to be changing quite a lot as as users' needs evolve -- developers generally want as much freedom as possible to change it, even completely changing its structure or throwing everything away and starting again.
Well-designed abstractions following OO principles should make the code easier to change.
Entity-Relationship-Modelling, Normalisation and Minimising Change
Unlike code, change to existing entities/relationships is something that you ideally want to avoid in a database, because redesigning a database containing your users' data is inherently risky as it generally involves a one-way irreversible migration process;  if that process goes wrong then it's a bad day, the best way to handle it is just not to do it in the first place unless you have no other choice.
When designing a database, forget Object-orientation and focus instead on normalisation and modelling your data in 3rd Normal Form (3NF).    Getting the data into 3NF should also help to minimise the need for any potentially-destructive changes in future as your users' needs evolve.
Object-Relational Mappers (ORMs)
Of course, there are ORM libraries which use programming language features such as classes to help programmers bridge the divide between the programming language and the database,  database tables can often conveniently be represented using classes,  however this is merely a way of using a programming language feature for convenience when working with databases.
The ORM 'data layer' in a program is usually the only place within the codebase where I would expect to see structures that mirror the database;   otherwise the code that models behaviour is most likely going to look completely different, since it exists for completely different reasons, with different concerns and different goals.
These 'entity' classes usually only represent fields/data without any behaviour (no validation, no calculations, etc);   as the data they represent doesn't "belong" to the program but to the database;  there's typically clean separation between classes containing this externally-owned data and the objects which model the program's behaviour/state.

"...  if that process goes wrong then it's a bad day..." — this reminds me of the old joke about what DBA stands for: Done Best After-hours.

"Relational Database design is about modelling persisted data" - I wouldn't say it's as simple as whether data is durably stored or not. SQL engines are primarily designed for processing (a) high volumes of (b) shared data. What we mean by (a) are volumes that potentially strain the best hardware economically available. And what we mean by (b) is hundreds or thousands of users making simultaneous queries on and changes to the same data. And it's designed to make programming these things trivial, by comparison to a fully-bespoke implementation in a comparatively low-level OO language.

@Steve Just to clarify, this answer is intentionally limited to looking at relational database design (Entity-relationship modelling)  from a conceptual point of view .  I'm intentionally ignoring all DBMS-specific implementation detail here, as I don't see anything in the question which seems to relate to concerns about data/user volumes, performance, economy, or hardware.  Am I missing something?   All of that seems completely out-of-scope for the question to me.

@BenCottrell, I was just addressing how your answer laid out the contrast between SQL design and OO design. I think a number of the claims were false (such as that SQL is not designed to "model runtime states and behaviours", that OO is more "high level", or that SQL is not designed for easy evolution), and others highly liable to be misinterpreted (such as saying database schemas are difficult and shouldn't change, when in fact client-server engines have the very best facilities available for fully-online, fully-transactional changes in procedures and data schemas!). (1/2)

SQL schemas are typically difficult to change either because they have already been put into shared use (and therefore downtime and alterations need to be coordinated widely), or because an OO application has been built on top of them which assumes the existing schema (and especially if the application has been built to manipulate the tables directly, rather than building and using a database API using stored procedure calls for all work, which would be the true OO style correctly applied to this situation). (2/2)

@Steve The answer didn't ever make the claim "SQL is not designed to model runtime states and behaviour".   I intentionally avoided making any reference to SQL (as that is a separate topic out of scope of the question).    However I made an edit earlier to remove the specific mention about persistence and clarified that I'm referring to relational database design being based on Entity-Relationship Modelling.     The answer also does not make any claim that OO is "more high level" than a relational database.    Nor does it make any claims about features about database engines

@Steve As per your comment: "SQL schemas are typically difficult to change either because they have already been put into shared use (and therefore downtime and alterations need to be coordinated widely" -- this is precisely what I meant by databases being more difficult to change;  i.e. the management of the migration and the risks involved with live/production data;   In other words, it's something you would want to minimise,  which is one of many reasons to decouple a program's behaviour away from the database structure.

@BenCottrell, yes but that's not attributable to the language or design environment, which you were addressing. With a client-server application written in an OO language, taking the shared server offline would be similarly difficult, and so would modifying its behaviour or data structures if it meant the clients all had to be updated and redeployed. Decoupling behaviour from data is, ironically, contrary to the OO principle that an object provides both data and behaviour. You decouple a database from a client application by providing a database API using stored procedure calls.

@Steve I'm afraid you've lost me now, I'm really struggling to see how anything you're saying relates in any way to my answer or the question for that matter.    I am not addressing anything to do with the language and not really sure what you mean by "design environment".    Furthermore I don't see what this has to do with client-server applications (there's nothing in the question nor my answer that seems to relate to this).     Also, Object-orientation goes heavily against coupling persisted data and behaviour;  OO is about having state and behaviour in the same object.

(Related thread covering reasons why "active record" is generally considered an OO anti-pattern:  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70291/what-are-the-drawbacks-to-the-activerecord-pattern )

@BenCottrell, it seemed to me you were saying that design in SQL should be done differently from design in OO languages. You then set out a list of differences between the two, which presumably justifies treating them differently - a list of differences which my comments relate to. But you can't see how any of this relates to your answer? (1/2)

As for client-server applications, you do realise that a client-server architecture (with concurrent multi-user access) is primarily what SQL engines are designed to cope with? And I know OO is about state and behaviour in the same object - that's why I'm saying, such a principle applied to databases, means treating the database as a complete object model, and accessing all state entirely through stored procedures. I'm not saying it has to be done that way, I'm just saying that is the correct way to approach it in a decoupled, OO way. (2/2)

@BenCottrell, regards the active record, I'm not seeing the relevance. I wasn't providing any prescription for how the objects are modelled in the client application. I was describing how the database itself is designed - every input and output must go through a stored procedure, an explicit interface. You can still do whatever you want on the client side - you just stop writing SELECT ... FROM and start writing EXEC .... (1/2)

And as I say, I'm not saying this approach is necessary or even always desirable - I'm just saying it's the approach which allows decoupling of the client from the data schema on the server, and it is the approach which is consistent with the OO approach of accessing all stored state through a callable interface. (2/2)

@Steve The answer has absolutely nothing to do with SQL engines nor the SQL language nor anything to do with any other such implementation-specific detail, as I don't see any of this being at all relevant to the question (Which I see as being based on some misconceptions about OO and ER modelling).   The point of the answer is to nudge the asker away from "OO" in their DB design and just focus on E-R modelling to identify entities and their relationships, then to normalise those;    concerns about database engines, and SQL implementation are out of scope for this thread in my opinion.

@BenCottrell, you talked of "relational databases" in the bolded first heading of your answer - those are synonymous with SQL engines and the SQL language. Moreover, even Relational Algebra as conceived by EF Codd, was published as a "model for large shared data banks" - in other words, it was inherently targeted to concurrent multi-user access to data from the outset. I don't want to push any further if you think these remarks are irrelevant, but I'm just completely lost by the things you are saying have no connection to your answer!

It's simply that I don't see these topics even being hinted at anywhere in the original question (even before it was rewritten), and I just find it unhelpful for Q+A answer threads go too far into unnecessary tangents.   I view the core of the originally-written question as being about modelling entities and relationships, with the OP looking to use OO methods (though the updated question doesn't read this way any more), so the focus of the answer is deliberately focused just on covering why E-R modelling and Normalisation are used for this rather than OO methods.
